# Jenkins deployment to windows

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, deployment

I want to automate deployment of my project from Jenkins on a Linux server to a Windows server. As I have read, there are some tools to scp from linux to windows. Is there a tool that I can use to push the build from linux using a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution should be to install a Jenkins slave agent on the Windows machine.

With this solution, you can create a dedicated job and launch it on the Windows node.

This job can get the artefact (or the build result) from the Linux server with the [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).